# Notifcation Access Denied - Android

Tags: android, listeners

Im creating an android app to access notifications. So far my NotificationListenerService cant access the notifications yet. It isnt on the list of allow apps notification access shown below. How may I enable that? My *Manifest.xml, MainActivity.java and MyNotificationListener.java* are as below

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="me.shikanga.NotificationListen2" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXRERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:resizeableActivity = "true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MyNotificationListener"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.notification.MyNotificationListener"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MyNotificationListener.java

```
package me.shikanga.NotificationListen2;

import android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService;
import android.content.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.util.*;
import android.app.*;
import android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService.*;
import android.service.notification.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import android.graphics.*;

public class MyNotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService
{
    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn, NotificationListenerService.RankingMap rankingMap)
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        super.onNotificationPosted(sbn, rankingMap);

    String pack = sbn.getPackageName();
    String ticker="";
    if(sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString()!=null)
    {
        ticker=sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();
    }
    Bundle extras=sbn.getNotification().extras;
    String title=extras.getString("android.title");
    String text= extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();
    int id1= extras.getInt(Notification.EXTRA_SMALL_ICON);
    Bitmap id = sbn.getNotification().largeIcon;

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),pack +title+text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.e("Posted", pack+ticker+title+text);
}

@Override
public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    super.onNotificationRemoved(sbn);

    String pack = sbn.getPackageName();
    Log.e("Removed", pack);
}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package me.shikanga.NotificationListen2;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.util.*;
import java.util.*;
import android.provider.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    Button startButton,stopButton;
    Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    startButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    stopButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
    context=getApplicationContext();

    if(!checkNotificationEnabled())
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Notification access denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e(getPackageName(), "Notification Access denied");
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Notification access enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e(getPackageName(), "Notification Access Enabled");

        //go to settimgs to enable notification access
        //startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS));
    }

    startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            try
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyNotificationListener.class);
                startService(i);

                Date date= new Date();
                Log.e(getPackageName()+" "+date.toString(),"MyNotificationListener service intent called sucessfully");
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), date.toString()+"Intent called successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to call intent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Date date = new Date();
                Log.e(getPackageName()+" "+date.toString(),"Failed to start MyNotificationListener Service");
            }
        }
    });

    stopButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                try
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyNotificationListener.class);
                    stopService(i);
                    Date date = new Date();
                    Log.e(getPackageName()+" "+date.toString(),"MyNotificationListener service stop intent called sucessfully");
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Intent called successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to call intent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Date date = new Date();
                    Log.e(getPackageName()+" "+date.toString(),"Failed to start MyNotificationListener Service");
                }
            }
        });
}


//Check of notification acccess is enabled
public boolean checkNotificationEnabled()
{
    String enabledListeners = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), "enabled_notification_listeners");
    String packageName= getPackageName();
    if (enabledListeners.contains(packageName))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
        {
            return false;
        }
}
}
```

Where should I modify? Thanks.
jerryshikanga@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know you can't enable the notification listening programmatically. In every device, you have to open the device settings and give access to any single app that want to read the notifications.